# How to write this line in JS.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I write this line in pure javascript and remove the jquery stance $?

```
 $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
```

Here is the full function that I'm using.

```
var tableOffset = $("#av-enrollment-table-header").offset().top;
      var $header = $("#av-enrollment-table-header > thead").clone();
      var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);

      $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
          var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

          if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
              $fixedHeader.show();
          }
          else if (offset < tableOffset) {
              $fixedHeader.hide();
          }
      });
```

Comment: Why you are removing event registration with jQuery method, when in callback you are still using jQuery?

Comment: i want to remove jquery from everywhere.

Comment: It is far more complicated to answer it...

Comment: In general, a code utilizing jQuery can't be written without jQuery in a simple way. A large part of the logic usually has to be re-written totally. Especially jQuery has its own event model, which keeps book of events internally, and makes all events bubble. That can't be replicated with simple vanilla event attaching. Also, jQuery fixes a ton of cross-browser issues, (even if we'd exclude support for old IEs), and it's a quite a job to add to a "translation" for all these fixes. Hence all "jQuery-to-vanilla JS" questions without clear limitations are far too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript "scroll" event:

```
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Comment: Can you do that  for thw whole function please?

Comment: Unforunately not - native javascript doesn't have an equivalent of jQuery's show() and hide(), which involves animation.

Comment: So, all I want to do is fix a table header when it reaches screen top. How can i make it work without jquery

Comment: What about this code. window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()}; 
function myFunction() {
   //Write the code here that you want to do in the scroll event
}

Comment: @princeyadav: if you don't need IE support, use CSS instead of JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Duncan: jQuery show() and hide() does not involve animation. Its just about target.style.display = 'block' and target.style.display = 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log(event)
}, false);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).